# Tidyverse suddenly disappeared. Error when installing a new tidyverse package

Tags: r, installation, tidyverse

My tidyverse package suddenly disappeared from my Rstudio showing error:

```
> library(tidyverse)
Error in library(tidyverse) : there is no package called ‘tidyverse’
```

But I have been using it everyday! So I tried to install the package again. However, I received error and warning and couldn't install the package:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
also installing the dependencies ‘lifecycle’, ‘tidyselect’, ‘rlang’, ‘cli’, ‘dplyr’, ‘vctrs’, ‘dbplyr’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
           binary source needs_compilation
lifecycle   1.0.1  1.0.3             FALSE
tidyselect  1.1.2  1.2.0             FALSE
rlang       1.0.2  1.0.6              TRUE
cli         3.2.0  3.4.1              TRUE
dplyr       1.0.8 1.0.10              TRUE
vctrs       0.4.0  0.5.0              TRUE
dbplyr      2.1.1  2.2.1             FALSE
tidyverse   1.3.1  1.3.2             FALSE



Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.6 is required


ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘lifecycle’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/lifecycle’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/lifecycle’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘tidyselect’ ...
** package ‘tidyselect’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 1.0.2 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.4 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘tidyselect’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/tidyselect’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/tidyselect’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyselect’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘dbplyr’ ...
** package ‘dbplyr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘cli’ 3.2.0 is already loaded, but >= 3.3.0 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘dbplyr’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/dbplyr’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/dbplyr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘dbplyr’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘tidyverse’ ...
** package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘lifecycle’ 1.0.0 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.1 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... namespaceImportFrom -> asNamespace -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘tidyverse’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/0s/n2561n1s57q5k3tzwf28mqhc0000gn/T/RtmpQrdwuG/downloaded_packages’
```

What is wrong? The codes below did not work:

(I found on stack overflow as someone said it might work. Not sure the meaning of it.)

```
sudo apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
```

It just shows 'Error: unexpected symbol in "sudo apt"'.

Unable to install 'tidyverse'
Want to know how to sort it out

Comment: It looks like you're on macos, I don't think `apt` or `apt-get` have any meaning there. Whatever recommended to you that you should use that `sudo` command line may have suggestions for macos (`brew ...`?). Regardless, that's an OS command, not an R command.

Comment: I don't understand how you reached to sudo. Nevertheles, run it in a linux console, not in R.

Comment: To be clear ... the mention of `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/` strongly suggests that you are on a Mac, not linux or other. Please clarify if this is not the case.

Comment: When it asks you if you want to install from source, it's safest to say "No" so you don't have to worry about compiling your packages. Are you sure you didn't update your version of R? If you change major versions, you need to reinstall packages. Packages shouldn't just disappear.

Comment: It's the newest version of Rstudio but not R. Should I update my R?